# Configuring Traffic Manager with Application Gateway

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I am trying to set up a new traffic manager profile for a pair of application gateways which are located in east and west using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure). These two gateways have some path based routing backends and rules. The routing method I want to choose for my new traffic manager is "Performance" and I want to add the public IPs of gateways as endpoints to it. But I am getting the following error.

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKOng.png)

In the dropdown for "Public IP Address", there is also this message - "cannot be associated with traffic manager endpoint". Any leads would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error observed here is due missing DNS Name on Public IP used. Please have look at this documentation for [additional details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-endpoint-types#azure-endpoints). You can follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#public-ip-address) to associate an Azure DNS record for your public IP

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the DNS zone and proper records. Else while adding endpoint you have to choose Endpoint type as "External" and add the appgateway's IP in the FQDN area. Refer the attached image. Please reply if it is worked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfwsd.png)